# How do I switch to the another Tab Screen?

Tags: flutter, switch-statement, tabbar

I want to switch to a another Screen, when i tap to the other icon on the tab bar but it does not work. I am always in HomeScreen() and I can´t switch to the HomeScreenMapView(). I think i have an issue at the return by the `ListView.builder` but i don´t know how i continue.

My Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import '../screens/home_screen.dart';
import '../screens/home_screen_map_view.dart';

class TabBarTop extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabBarTopState createState() => _TabBarTopState();
}

class _TabBarTopState extends State<TabBarTop> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _isAppbar = true;
      ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _scrollController.addListener(() {
          if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
              ScrollDirection.reverse) {
            appBarStatus(false);
          }
          if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
              ScrollDirection.forward) {
            appBarStatus(true);
          }
        });
      }

      void appBarStatus(bool status) {
        setState(() {
          _isAppbar = status;
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12),
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                height: _isAppbar ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1 : 0.0,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                child: CustomAppBar(),
              ),
            ),
            body: ListView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return HomeScreen();
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class CustomAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      AppBarView createState() => new AppBarView();
    }

    class AppBarView extends State<CustomAppBar> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
          return [
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Center(
                heightFactor: 0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/***.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    scale: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.007,
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
              primary: true,
              floating: true,
              pinned: true,
              bottom: TabBar(
                indicatorColor: Color.fromRGBO(253, 166, 41, 1.0),
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  Tab(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              forceElevated: false,
              flexibleSpace: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: <Color>[
                      Color.fromRGBO(107, 176, 62, 1.0),
                      Color.fromRGBO(153, 199, 58, 1.0),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            HomeScreen(),
            HomeScreenMapView(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
      }
    }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: can you explain actually what behaviour you are expecting. i mean what you want in this screen overall.

Comment: i want to switch to the HomeScreenMapView(), when i tap on the location icon on the tab bar but i see always the HomeScreen(), when i tap on both icons. @VirenVVarasadiya

Comment: it obvious but i can not understand that do you want to build list base on tab. for example if 1st tab selected then list with HomeScreen and on 2nd tab  list with HomeScreenMapView?

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya yes the 1st tab HomeScreen() = ListView.builder Screen and the second tab should be a Google Maps Screen (HomeScreenMapView().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need TabBarTop class to achieve so, you can only go with CustomAppBar class which provide that facility.

I don't know how much i currently understand your question and need but i am answering it.

Hope following code help you.

Directly call TabBarTop from your main.

```
   class TabBarTop extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabBarTopState createState() => _TabBarTopState();
}

class _TabBarTopState extends State<TabBarTop>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  expandedHeight: 50.0,
                  floating: true,
                  snap: true,
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                      centerTitle: true,
                      title: Text("Collapsing Toolbar",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          )),
                      background: Image.network(
                        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )),
                ),
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                  delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                    TabBar(
                      labelColor: Colors.black87,
                      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info), text: "Tab 1"),
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline), text: "Tab 2"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  pinned: true,
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: TabBarView(
              children: <Widget>[
                HomeScreen(),
                Container(
                  child: Center(child: Text("cds2")),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemExtent: 150,
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return Text("csca $index");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

  final TabBar _tabBar;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: _tabBar,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: but if i execute this my animation is lost. i want that to persist. That when I scroll down, the app and tabbar disappear and when I scroll up, the app bar and tabbar reappears at the HomeScreen().

Comment: firstly, thanks for your help but the app and tab bar reappears only when i am on the top of the listview.builder. but i want the app and tab bar visible or unvisible, when i make the move to scroll up or down. you know what i mean? Sorry about the circumstances.

Comment: can you give it a try. i changed code. check this out. https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-sliverappbar-examples

Comment: the tool bar works how it should work but the tab bar is not visible WITH the toolbar if i scroll up or down. its just visible on the top of the list. 
thanks for the website :)

Update: i found the solution!

Comment: Glad to hear that you found solution. can you edit my answer because my emulator is laggy and so it is difficult find changes. And accept my answer if it is useful.